# Under what situation include_directory does not work in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am working on a very large project using CMake. I tried to add additional include path but failed.

The following works (with -I at the compile command)

```
include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

The following works (with -I at  the compile command, same as ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/abc, the path does not exist)

```
include_directories(
    abc
)
```

The following works too (/abc does not exist).

```
include_directories(
    /abc
)
```

The following does not (-I command omits this line)

```
include_directories(
    /usr/include
)
```

So under what situation the include_directories will ban some path? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember, CMake may do not emit include path, which is same as a system one. In you case `/usr/include` may be ignored because the compiler already uses this path for search headers.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/include` is a standard include path, therefore CMake does not add it to the `-I` option - the compiler already knows that path. All others will we added.

---

Maybe interesting too:

> If the SYSTEM option is given, the compiler will be told the
>   directories are meant as system include directories on some platforms.
>   Signalling this setting might achieve effects such as the compiler
>   skipping warnings, or these fixed-install system files not being
>   considered in dependency calculations - see compiler docs.
>   ([source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html#command:include_directories))

Therefore you may want to use

```
include_directories(
    SYSTEM
        /usr/include
)
```

But in general it is not a good idea to use `SYSTEM`. If you really have to use it - it mostly a symptom of a bigger problem underlying.